# Why isn't my CSS fallback value being applied?

Tags: html, css, css-variables

What I'm trying to do is whenever I delete the variable `--mainColor` in the `:root` the border-color will change to black and text to red but it will be the same as the fallback value of the color. Why does this happen?

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-color: var(--mainColor, black);
  color: var(--mainColor, red);
  padding: var(--mainPadding, 10px);
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div>Element</div>
<div>Element</div>
<div>Element</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The `border` property is shorthand for `border-width`, `border-style`, and `border-color`. Therefore, it overrides your earlier rule. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Becase you're overriding the `border-color` using `border` property, which uses `currentColor` by default if you don't specificy color.

```css
:root {
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid; /* moved here */
  border-color: var(--mainColor, black);
  color: var(--mainColor, red);
  padding: var(--mainPadding, 10px);
}
```

```html
<div>Element</div>
<div>Element</div>
<div>Element</div>
```

Or use `border-style` instead of `border` to prevent overriding.

```css
:root {
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-color: var(--mainColor, black);
  color: var(--mainColor, red);
  padding: var(--mainPadding, 10px);
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div>Element</div>
<div>Element</div>
<div>Element</div>
```